# Partial effects whithout ceteris paribus assumption

Tags: partial-effect

Is it possible to estimate the partial effect of the exogenous variables without holding other variables constant, in other words without ceteris paribus assumption? I know that in normal case we need to hold other variables constant to find a partial effect of one variable, but I have this question in the exam questions list, so I am also confused and I hope that someone can help me to clarify this question.